# React.js height 100%

Tags: reactjs, web, height

estoy intentando hacer mi primera app web con react.js y necesito que mi  ocupe todo el alto de la página. Vi que poniendo lo siguiente en "App.css" era suficiente:

```
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

**Luego tengo un display grid**:

```
#App{
  display: grid;
  gap: 3px;
  grid-template: 
    "header      header"
    "subjectsbar writearea"
}
```

Pero no me funciona en react, simplemente se ve como si nada ocurriese, si saben como solucionarlo por favor contactarse.

Comment: Has probado con `100vh`?

Comment: Creo que estas mezclando un poco los conceptos, intenta agregar ese `height: 100%` en `#app` al igual que la propiedad `min-height`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justo puedes modificar los estilos de la aplicación que se genera automáticamente en React desde App.css siempre que tu componente App se esté cargando, ahora, si estás seguro de ello, sugiero no colocar a los tags html y body estos estilos pues podría decir que el navegador ya los despliega en este tamaño que viene a ser el tamaño de la ventana, ahora, ¿Cómo hacer que tu componente raíz se vea a toda la pantalla?, en el entendido que tu componente App se encuentra cargado dentro de root y este se carga dentro del tag body entonces a tu componente App hay que agregar una clase css.

```
return (<App className="general" />);
```

y en CSS manejar la clase de la siguiente forma...

```
// Sugiero hacer siempre esto, remueve márgenes generados automáticamente por el navegador
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.general {
    height: 100vh; // Alto de la ventana
    width: 100vw; // Ancho de la ventana
    background-color: purple; // Solo para ver el resultado
}
```

Si todo está en su lugar, podrás ver un resultado parecido:
[image: Componente App al 100% de alto de la ventana y 100% ancho de la ventana]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4fkN.png): [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me funcionó perfectamente, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: A ti por puntuar. ¡Saludos!